# Kubernetes - Max concurrent request limit for "Service" at a time

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

What is the Maximum number of request can a Kubernetes Service handle in parellel. I will be providing auto scaling for the pods to scale based on the input request, but is there any limit for the maximum number of request which a Service can handle at a point of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services in Kubernetes are just routing configurations in the kernel. When you call a Service URL/IP your local kernel will forward the request to a random Pod.

Therefore the request limit is defined by the number of requests a single node of your cluster can handle.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Want to get more clarity on this. Is this applicable for all external http request as well ? Lets say I use a Nodeport Service, the total number of external http requests, this NodePort service can handle at a time is dependent on number of request a single node can handle ?